# 70-persistent-net.rules file $attr{phys_switch_id} used to call script. How this value will be fetched and from where these values are defined

Tags: linux, networking, udev

I am new to udev rules and trying to call a script which need physical switch ID to perform some operations. Now, I have defined a rule as below.

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", c=="[0-9]*", PROGRAM="/etc/udev/runner.py eswitch $attr{phys_switch_id} $attr{phys_port_name}", NAME="%c"
```

1. Where `$attr{phys_switch_id}` is defined?
2. How the udev rules will interpret this value as input argument to the script.

Please help me to understand.

Comment: $attr{file}, %s{file}
The value of a sysfs attribute found at the device, where all keys of the rule have matched. If the matching device does not have such an attribute, follow the chain of parent devices and use the value of the first attribute that matches. If the attribute is a symlink, the last element of the symlink target is returned as the value

Comment: But, in case of new ethernet card, from where these values get fetched ?